# Setting legend entries manually

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am using openpyxl to create charts. For some reason, I do not want to insert row names when adding data. So, I want to edit the legend entries manually. I am wondering if anyone know how to do this.
More specifically 
`class openpyxl.chart.legend.Legend(legendPos='r', legendEntry=(), 
     layout=None, overlay=None, spPr=None, txPr=None, extLst=None)`. I want to edit the legendEntry field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that. You need to set the rows when creating the plots. That will create the titles for your charts